# why is the client not seeing the first message sent by the server?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

First, here is my server. Please look at this part

```
if(clients.size() == 2){

    sendStartSignal();
    break;

}
```

In the above part, i send a start signal "start" string when at least two clients connect to the server.

Server code begins here....

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

using namespace std;


void * handle_client(void * ptr);


void sendStartSignal();


struct thdata{

    int client_no;

};


vector<pthread_t *> clients;
vector<int> client_nos;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;
    socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(client_addr);
    int option, port, reuse;
    int server, client;
    int nread;

    // setup default arguments
    port = 3000;

    // process command line options using getopt()
    // see "man 3 getopt"
    while ((option = getopt(argc,argv,"p:")) != -1) {
        switch (option) {
            case 'p':
                port = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "server [-p port]" << endl;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

      // setup socket address structure
    memset(&server_addr,0,sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

      // create socket
    server = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if (!server) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

      // set socket to immediately reuse port when the application closes
    reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(-1);
    }

      // call bind to associate the socket with our local address and
      // port
    if (bind(server,(const struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(-1);
    }

      // convert the socket to listen for incoming connections
    if (listen(server,SOMAXCONN) < 0) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(-1);
    }



      // accept clients
    while ((client = accept(server,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&clientlen)) > 0) {


        //make the clients non blocking
        fcntl(client, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);



        pthread_t* th = new pthread_t;
        thdata* data = new thdata;
        data->client_no = client;


        clients.push_back(th);
        client_nos.push_back(client);


         pthread_create(th, NULL, &handle_client, (void *) data);


        if(clients.size() == 2){

        sendStartSignal();
        break;

        }

    }





for(int i=0;i<clients.size();i++){

    pthread_join(*clients[i], NULL);

}




}



void sendStartSignal(){


    char *buf;
    int buflen;
    int nread;
    // allocate buffer
    buflen = 1024;
    buf = new char[buflen+1];


    buf[0] = 's';
    buf[1] = 't';
    buf[2] = 'a';
    buf[3] = 'r';
    buf[4] = 't';
    buf[5] = 0;


            for(int i = 0;i<clients.size();i++) {

             send(client_nos[i], buf, 6, 0);


            }


}



void * handle_client(void * ptr){


        thdata * data = (thdata*) ptr;


        char *buf;
        int buflen;
        int nread;
        // allocate buffer
        buflen = 1024;
        buf = new char[buflen+1];


        int client_no = data->client_no;



        // loop to handle all requests
        while (1) {

              // read a request
            memset(buf,0,buflen);

            nread = recv(client_no,buf,buflen,0);


            if(nread >= 0){


                if(nread == 0) {

                    int index_to_delete = -1;

                    for(int i=0;i<client_nos.size();i++){

                        if(client_nos[i] == client_no){

                            index_to_delete = 0;
                            break;

                        }

                    }

                    clients.erase(clients.begin() + index_to_delete);
                    client_nos.erase(client_nos.begin() + index_to_delete);


                    break;
                }



            for(int i = 0;i<clients.size();i++) {


                if (client_nos[i] != client_no){
                    send(client_nos[i], buf, nread, 0);
                }

            }




            }


        }



}
```

Now, here is my client in java

Please look at this part...

```
public static void handle_read(){


            while(true){

                         try{   

                             String line = r.readLine();
                             System.out.println(line);

                        }

                        catch(Exception e){

                          System.err.println(e);

                        }
                     }


}
```

In the above part, it is a thread that just reads incoming message from the server. Now, my question is, as you can see in server code that as soon as  two connections are made, "start" signal is sent to the clients....now, the client doesnt print start as soon as two clients connect to the server...it only prints "start" after i send some message to the server. Why is this so?

Client starts here ....

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Client 
   {



   public static BufferedReader r;
   public static PrintWriter w;


    public static void main(String[] args){


            try
            {
                Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 3000);

                r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                w = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));



                Thread t1 = new Thread(){

                    public void run(){

                        handle_read();

                    }

                };


                Thread t2 = new Thread(){

                    public void run(){

                        handle_write();

                    }


                };


                t1.start();
                t2.start();

                t1.join();
                t2.join();


                System.out.println("Exiting .... ");





            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                System.err.println(err);
            }






}


public static void handle_read(){


            while(true){

                    try{    
                          String line = r.readLine();
                          System.out.println(line);
                        }

                        catch(Exception e){

                             System.err.println(e);

                        }
                    }



}


public static void handle_write(){



            while(true){

                         try{

                            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String s = scan.next();

                            w.println(s);

                         }
                         catch(Exception e){

                             System.err.println(e);

                        }   

                     }


}



    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Don't post [EXACT same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295038/client-not-reading-the-first-message-from-the-server) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending this message:

```
buf[0] = 's';
buf[1] = 't';
buf[2] = 'a';
buf[3] = 'r';
buf[4] = 't';
buf[5] = 0;
```

Then you are reading it with this code

```
String line = r.readLine();
```

This seems like a mismatch. You are not sending a line, but you are trying to read a line.

End the message you send with a newline character, '\n'